# begininvoke appears not to execute in runtime on some pc's

Tags: vb.net, winforms, vb.net-2010

Have spent a significant amount of time researching this and cannot find a similar issue on any of numerous forums but if anyone can point me to one please do (i ask q's as a last resort!)

I have the following code I inherited which has been working fine until an update on Friday!

The slightly puzzling factor is the code executes perfectly in debug and runtime on my PC and has worked perfectly on my clients until Friday but now will not execute on their machines at all!

i am running VS 2010 on a W7 64 bit and the clients machines are all XP 32 bit, excuse the re-emphasis but the first section of code has not changed since i took the project on in April and there has been numerous updates issued since then all functioning correctly (including one at the beginning of last week).

```
Delegate Sub ACCSheetBG()
Dim ACC As New ACCSheetBG(AddressOf Me.ACCSheet)
Dim ACCDone As IAsyncResult

Private Sub AM_CreateSpreadsheet_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles AM_CreateSpreadsheet.Click
    Dim Test1 As Boolean = True
    Try
        Test1 = ACCDone.IsCompleted
    Catch ex As Exception
        'If Here Assume It Is Just Failed because not used before and that it is ok to start.
        GoTo Skip1
    End Try
    If ACCDone.IsCompleted = True Then
Skip1:
        If MsgBox("This process may take several minutes." & Chr(13) & "You can perform other operations whilst this is processing.", MsgBoxStyle.Information + MsgBoxStyle.OkCancel, "Accounts Generation") = MsgBoxResult.Ok Then
            'Start Accounts Sheet
            ACCDone = ACC.BeginInvoke(Nothing, Nothing)
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox("Operation already in progress", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Already Running")
    End If
End Sub
```

The section of code above has NOT changed at all! (despite my personal thoughts on the way it is written!)

the Sub it is calling has changed but i inserted a msgbox before any other statements and this never appears:

*****See new info at bottom*****

```
Public Sub ACCSheet()

    MsgBox("StartACC")

    'Some code

End Sub
```

When the button `AM_CreateSpreadsheet` is clicked you get the msgbox cautioning you that the process will take some time, the msgbox on the first line of `ACCSheet` never gets executed.

there has been some changes within `Sub ACCSheet()` but as it does not appear to execute this code this is unlikely to be the cause.

**New Info**

Hans Passant's answer (unfortunately he has now removed it or i would mark it as an answer) gave me a tip off so i commented out all added code and sure enough the issue disappeared, the problem section turned out to be where i was adding a VBA to the created spreadsheet (yes i had gone in and turned on 'Trust access to the VBA project object model' on the target machine).

What is puzzling me still is this section of code was in a try, catch and the msgbox referred to above was before the try, catch and not only was the msgbox not displayed but the msgbox in the catch part of the statement was not displayed.
(also the application performed perfectly on some XP 32 bit machines but not on others)

The problem causing code was:

```
Dim oModule As Vbe.Interop.VBComponent
Dim SCode As String
' Create a new VBA code module.
oModule = ExAccBk.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(VBIDE.vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_StdModule)
        SCode = "Function SUMCOLOR(ColorCell As Range, SumRange As Range) As Variant" & vbCrLf & _
"Dim Cell As Range" & vbCrLf & _
"For Each Cell In SumRange" & vbCrLf & _
"If Cell.Interior.Color = ColorCell.Interior.Color Then" & vbCrLf & _
"SUMCOLOR = Cell + SUMCOLOR" & vbCrLf & _
"End If" & vbCrLf & _
"Next" & vbCrLf & _
"SUMCOLOR = SUMCOLOR" & vbCrLf & _
"End Function"
' Add the VBA macro to the new code module.
oModule.CodeModule.AddFromString(SCode)
```

I would love to know why this caused a problem and how to re-include and most importantly why it appeared not to run!

Hans suggested a BackgroundWorker which i am going to try but i would still appreciate an explanation if anyone has one to offer.

**Latest Info**

Have now tried the Background worker without any advantage, @jcwrequests has given me the clue to locating the cause - it is the version of Excel that is causing the issue (works on 2010 but not 2007)

Will now do a bit of research on adding VBA modules to Excel 2007!

**Final Update (hopefully)**

Now here is a conundrum, i finally resurrected an old laptop with VS on it running Office 2007 on XP and tried the program in debug and yes it executes the code in debug but not in Runtime on the same machine!!! as per above the code simply appears not to get executed.

I am going to run a workaround on this one but will keep watching the thread so if someone ever comes up with a solution i will be glad to hear!

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that you application need to be set to 32bit and rebuilt but that is assuming you are accessing the excel data using ADO.NET because there are no 64bit drivers. Can you provide more information.

Comment: unfortunately this is not the case (i am successfully running the application on some 32 bit pc's but it fails on others - i am updating the question as i have found out some more info.

Comment: I feel you pain. The problem often time using Excel is that depending on version you get different results.  So you may be running into an issue with what version is running on the end users machine.  I have seen the issue a thousand times.  It works 2003 not 2007.  You get the idea.  Any way sounds like a deployment issue.